# Why just the last url on array is used on curl

Tags: php, arrays, curl

i found a bug with my code , when i put some values on array $url just the last value is used on the process. 
I really don't know what is the problem , if anyone help me i will be good

```
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
    <textarea name="url">site</textarea>
    <input type=submit value="EXPLOITAR">
</form>
</body>
<?php
$link = $_POST['url'];
$a = explode(";", $link);
function geralink($a){
    return("$a".'index.php');
}
$url =array_map("geralink" , $a);
// loop for curl_setopt
foreach( $url as $key => $url){
    $mh = curl_multi_init();
    $ch[$key] = curl_init($url);

    // set URL and other appropriate options
    curl_setopt($ch[$key], CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt($ch[$key], CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch[$key], CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36');
    curl_setopt($ch[$key], CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch[$key], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_multi_add_handle($mh , $ch[$key]);
}
do {
    curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
    curl_multi_select($mh);
} while ($running > 0);

// loop for the responses codes 
foreach(array_keys($ch) as $key){
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch[$key], CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $effurl  = curl_getinfo($ch[$key], CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
    if(curl_errno($ch[$key]) === TRUE){   
        echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch[$key]);
    }else{
        echo "CODE: $httpcode URL: $effurl <br>";
        echo "\n";
    }
    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch[$key]);
}
curl_multi_close( $mh)
?>
```

sorry for the horrible english guys xd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initializing curl multi inside the loop, so that is why it works only for the last url. You must initialize curl multi before the loop:

```
$url =array_map("geralink" , $a);
$mh = curl_multi_init(); //Yes, here

// loop for curl_setopt
foreach( $url as $key => $url){
    //$mh = curl_multi_init(); //Not here
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using same var name for urls array and url item:

```
$url =array_map("geralink" , $a);
// loop for curl_setopt
foreach( $url as $key => $url){
```

Much better:

```
$urls =array_map("geralink" , $a);
// loop for curl_setopt
foreach( $urls as $key => $url){
```

Comment: i think wasn't that

Comment: I'm sorry, look my new answer.